# How do I prevent text selection on my website?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, textbox, textarea

I am working on an internal website for a company and they requested that I disable text selection as well as right click. They want text selection disabled mainly to prevent people from using Control+C to copy since right click is disabled.

I have been requested to allow text selection in textboxes as well as textfields. I managed to get this working except for the fact that in Internet Explorer, users can't select in text boxes. Chrome allows text selection in textboxes.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
                var msgpopup="This action is disabled.";
                function killCopy(e){
                    return false
                }
                function reEnable(){
                    return true
                }
                document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")

                if (window.sidebar){
                    document.onmousedown=killCopy
                    document.onclick=reEnable
                }
                function handle(){
                      if(toShowMessage== "1") alert(message);
                      if(closeSelf== "1") self.close();
                      return false;
                }
                function mouseDown() {
                     if (event.button == "2" || event.button == "3"){handle();}
                }
                function mouseUp(e) {
                     if (e.which == "2" || e.which == "3"){ handle();}
                }
                document.onmousedown=mouseDown;
                document.onmouseup=mouseUp;
                document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(msgpopup);return false")
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function right(e) { 
                    if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2)) 
                        return false; 
                    else if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && (event.button == 2 || event.button == 3)) { 
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true; 
                    } 
                    document.onmousedown=right; 
                    if (document.layers) window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); window.onmousedown=right; 
            </script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: \*facepalm\* \*facepalm\* \*facepalm\* I hope *you* know that this doesn't do anything, really, even if your company doesn't.

Comment: Yes I know users can still get passed it, however I was requested to do it even after I explained it to them.

Comment: OK, verbal +1 for that. :)

Comment: @Diodeus I'm not sure how closed questions work and I don't know If you are getting notifications of my edits so I'm just posting this comment to make sure you get a notification.

Comment: @AliHamze If a question is edited after it's closed, it enters the Reopen Votes review queue, where members with >3K rep consider whether the edit justifies reopening the question. I just gave you a reopen vote. If four other reviewers agree, it will be reopened.

Comment: @AdiInbar Great, thanks. I see that its reopened now :)

Comment: In IEs this can be achieved like at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgGW2/), though some security settings might override the script. In Chrome and FF this seems to block the contextmenu. In Chrome `CTRL+A` is blocked, but mouse selection can still be used. In FF any of selection modes is not blocked. Hence there's still some job for you to do.

Comment: @Teemu Awesome, post that as answer so I can accept it. I managed to get it working using that for Internet Explorer and CSS -user-select for Chrome/Firefox. I used the same right click script that I had above in my original question.